# Am I using Infura with Web3j correctly?

Tags: web3js, infura

This is the first time using infura with a Web3j HttpClient. I have seen people use a code after the url like this: "infura.io/--here--". Am I using Infura correctly?

This is my code. (web3j v3.5.0)

```
Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://rinkeby.infura.io/"));
Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = null;                

try {
    web3ClientVersion = web3.web3ClientVersion().send();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String web3ClientVersionString = web3ClientVersion.getWeb3ClientVersion();
System.out.println("Web3 client version: " + web3ClientVersionString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an infura account, and get the infura link with your API key at the end of it. It will look like a bunch of letters. Go to infura.io for this.

Comment: I have a project in infura, add the address of the contract that I am going to use. Is the link I have to use the "endpoint"?

Comment: Could be. It depends on the context. HTTP endpoint can be used to describe this link, yes

Comment: this is the link "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/etc,etc,etc", with this I could connect to my contract and make transactions?

Comment: Yes yes yes yes